# Buttons in updatepanel with timer doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, updatepanel

I have this code. When I click any button doesn't work. I want all buttons run EventHandler(Button1_Click). I had tried to use multiple AsyncPostBackTrigger but then timer method stuck.

```
public DataTable data1 = new DataTable();
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e){
        MySqlConnection con = openconnection();
        MySqlDataAdapter sda1 = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT id FROM orderprogress WHERE Order=0;", con);
        sda1.Fill(data1);

        for (int i = 0; i < data1.Rows.Count; i++){
            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
            cell1.Text = data1.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            row.Cells.Add(cell1);
            Table1.Rows.Add(row);
            insertbuttons(i);
            }
}
void insertbuttons(int i){
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.ID = data1.Rows[i][0].ToString();
        btn.Text = "Apply!";
        btn.Click += new EventHandler(Button1_Click);
        TableRow row1 = new TableRow();
        TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
        row1.Cells.Add(cell2);
        Table1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Controls.Add(btn);
    }
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
        orderidlb.Text = "button pressed";
    }
```

Here the asp code i used:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Interval="10"></asp:Timer>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
                <asp:TableRow>
                    <asp:TableCell>ID</asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TableCell>test BTN!</asp:TableCell>
                </asp:TableRow>
            </asp:Table>
      </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Have you tried AutoPostBack="true" on your buttons?

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but so far I've found that the button doesn't fire until the interval on the timer has completed BUT if your interval is too low then the interval fires again prior to the button being able to fully fire, thus nullifying the button click.  Your timer is ticking every 1/100th of a second, which is waaaay too fast.  Try increasing to 1 second (Interval="1000")and I think you'll find that your button works.  If you increase the interval too far, like 10 seconds for example, you will click the button and seemingly nothing will happen but about 10 seconds later the command will fire.  Weird behavior, I'm still trying to find an instant solution, but this is what I've got in the interim.